# Pass associative array to Javascript using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am learning Programming. Can anyone help me to pass this associative array to JavaScript using AJAX?

server.php

```
$sql = "SELECT Lng, Lat, URL FROM results LIMIT 1000";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
     {
         $data = json_encode($row["Lng"].$row["Lat"]. urlencode($row["URL"])."<br>");
         $param = $_POST['param'];
         $param = json_decode($param);
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Index.js

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'server.php',
    data: {param: ""},
   success: function() 
    {
        console.log("Testing");
    }
});
```

Comment: json_encode from php side and you will get from ajax response after JSON.parse it.

Comment: `server.php` is a mess. What is `$param = $_POST['param']` and why is it in your while loop?

Comment: You are not writing the data when fetched

Comment: what you are trying to do i am not quite understand your code ?

Comment: Why you're not using `$data` variable?

Comment: You mean  $param = $_POST['data'];

Comment: No I mean `$data = json_encode($row["Lng"].$row["Lat"]. urlencode($row["URL"])."<br>");`, you construct it but never use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the data back from the server side as an argument of success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'server.php',
    data: {param: ""},
    success: function(response) 
    {
        console.log( JSON.parse( response ) );
    }
});
```

**NOTE 1:** You should really arrange the code in your server side.

**NOTE 2:** If you're using `json_encode()` in your server-side script to send a JSON format as a response, you need to use `JSON.parse()` in the client side to decode the JSON.

Comment: Don't worry @kerbholz, the downvoters are everywhere just ignore them and keep going.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow world :D

Answer (score 0):

In your **server.php**  you need to json_encode and not decode:

```
$response = array("coordinates" => array());
$sql = "SELECT Lng, Lat, URL FROM results LIMIT 1000";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $response["coordinates"][] = $row;
        }
    }

echo json_encode($response);
$conn->close();
```

And the request (index.js) like:

```
   $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'server.php',
      data: [],
      success: function(response){console.log(response);}
    });
```

You have to respond a JSON, otherwise it won't work. It should be as simple as:

```
echo json_encode($array)
```